# Laravel 5 if condition not working on last condition (else)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a text field `status-text` that allows users to submit their statuses.

I also have an image upload field to add a picture to the status.

In my if condition, I am checking first to see if the input has any data, then I check if the input has an image AND validator doesn't fail, then I check if validator doesn't fail (to submit a status without an image), at the end I do an `else` which is supposed to be "if input doesn't have any data"

The first 3 checks are working but the last `else` is not. Apparently the code is not reaching that final else for some reason.

This is the view

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
@endif
@include('partials/flash')
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {!! Form::open(['files' => true]) !!}
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Add New Status</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="status-text">Write Something</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="status-text" id="status-text"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
                                <i class="fa fa-image"></i>
                            </label>
                            <input id="file-upload" name="status_image_upload" type="file">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Status</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this is `FeedController@index`

```
if($request->has('status-text')) {
        $text = Input::get('status-text');

        $rules = [
            'status-text' => 'required|string'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if($request->hasFile('status_image_upload') && !$validator->fails()) {
            $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');

            $imageName = str_random(8) . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            //$imageFull = str_random(8) . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();

            $image->move('uploads/status_images', $imageName);

            $userStatus = new Status;
            $userStatus->status_text = $text;
            $userStatus->image_url = $imageName;
            $userStatus->type = 1;
            $userStatus->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus->save();
            flash('Your status has been posted');

            return redirect(route('feed'));
        } elseif(!$validator->fails()) {
            $userStatus = new Status;
            $userStatus->status_text = $text;
            $userStatus->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus->save();
            flash('Your status has been posted', 'success');

            return redirect(route('feed'));
        } else {
            $messages = $validator->errors();
            return redirect(route('feed'))->withErrors($messages);
        }
```

I have tried using `if($validator->fails())` - it didn't work.
I have also tried returning a simple string `return 'field cannot be empty';` just to test it out, it doesn't work either.

I have the same code running for `post_comment` and it works for the `else`, so if I leave the comment field empty and submit it, I get redirected to the feed page with an error message saying the field cannot be empty.

**THIS WORKS**

```
if(Input::has('post_comment')) {
        $rules = [
            'comment-text' => 'required|string'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        if(!$validator->fails()) {
            $status = Input::get('post_comment');
            $commentBox = Input::get('comment-text');
            $selectedStatus = Status::find($status);

            $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
                'comment_text' => $commentBox,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'status_id' => $status
            ]);

            flash('Your comment has been posted', 'success');

            return redirect(route('feed'));
        } else {
            $messages = $validator->errors();
            return redirect(route('feed'))->withErrors($messages);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudo-code, you **say** you're trying to do this

```
if input exists
  if image exists and validator passes

  elsif validator passes

  end
else 
  // no data
end
```

but your code says you're doing this

```
if input exists
  if image exists and validator passes

  elsif validator passes

  else 
    // no data
  end
end
```

I would refactor this entirely. Program defensively.

```
if no data
  // handle no data
  return;
end

if validator fails
  // handle invalid data
  return;
end

create new Status

if image exists
  // handle image upload
end

flash message
redirect
```

If you do this you'll remove the duplication with your validation checks, creating a Status, flashing a message, and redirecting.

Try to avoid nesting conditionals. Try to avoid `else` and `else if` statements. Your code will be cleaner and more readable as a result.

Answer (score 0):

If your text field is empty on submit it will not be in request.

Comment: Although the limitations on commenting while not having enough reputation are understandable, please refrain from posting comments as answers. If you know you have an answer to this question, please, edit it, elaborate it respecting the [StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for writing good answers.